# Issue with gyroscope and accelerometer

Tags: ios, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope, lowpass-filter

I'm developing an Application that connects to a [TiSensorTag](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Bluetooth_SensorTag) device and uses its gyroscope and accelerometer together to detect position and movements. My prior problem is that when I retrieve accelerometer and gyroscope data I get values that are never fixes but fluctuate between a small interval of values.
I applied a low-pass filter but obviously my values continue to oscillate even though my sensor device is motionless.
So, I can't recognize if my TiSesorTag is really fixed or not.

Could you suggest me a way to overcome this issue, please? Thanks

Here is my code where I get values:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {

if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:[self.d.setupData valueForKey:@"Accelerometer data UUID"]]]) {

    float xf= [sensorKXTJ9 calcXValue:characteristic.value];
    float yf= [sensorKXTJ9 calcYValue:characteristic.value];
    float zf= [sensorKXTJ9 calcZValue:characteristic.value];

    NSMutableArray *newValues= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:xf],
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:yf],
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:zf],
                                nil];

    self.currentVal.accX = [[newValues objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    self.currentVal.accY = [[newValues objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];;
    self.currentVal.accZ = [[newValues objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];;

    [self applyLowPassFilter:newValues];

    NSLog(@"Accelerometer: X: % 0.1fG Y: % 0.1fG Z: % 0.1fG", self.currentVal.accX, self.currentVal.accY, self.currentVal.accZ);
}
if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:[self.d.setupData valueForKey:@"Gyroscope data UUID"]]]) {

    float x = [self.gyroSensor calcXValue:characteristic.value];
    float y = [self.gyroSensor calcYValue:characteristic.value];
    float z = [self.gyroSensor calcZValue:characteristic.value];

    self.currentVal.gyroX = x;
    self.currentVal.gyroY = y;
    self.currentVal.gyroZ = z;

    NSLog(@"Gyroscope: X: % 0.1f°/S Y: % 0.1f°/S Z: % 0.1f°/S", self.currentVal.gyroX, self.currentVal.gyroY, self.currentVal.gyroZ);
}
```

}